# Undoing local merge if remote gets updated

Tags: git

I have the following `git` workflow:

```
# finish locally committing to feature/new_thing
git push origin feature/new_thing
git checkout develop
git pull # Just in case I get a warning
git merge feature/new_thing
git push origin develop
```

This works 99% of the time, but the other 1% of the time, this happens:

```
#Me                             #Other dev
git push origin feature/new_thing
                                git merge feature/other_new_thing
git checkout develop
                                git checkout develop
git pull
                                git pull
git merge feature/new_thing
                                git merge feature/other_new_thing
                                git push origin develop
git push origin develop
```

Now, my `push` predictably fails with:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@server.git'
```

What is the easiest way to get myself back in sync? `git reset HEAD~` deletes my branch commit, and `git pull` wants to merge again. I usually end up `reset`ting back to before the branch and re-`pull`ing my check-in

There has to be a simple way to do this! I did try using `git-workflow` for a bit, but it often got stuck and required even more manual intervention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your push fails, you know the remote must have updated, so your local `origin/develop` copy is out of date. I like to know what changed before deciding how to deal with it, so I usually run

```
$ git fetch
```

first, so I can look at `git log --all --graph --decorate` or `gitk --all` or similar.

If you decide you want to rebase your commit on top of the latest, you can just use

```
$ git pull --rebase
```

If it's not a clean rebase you'll get into fixing it up by hand - if you think that's going to happen (or it already did and you ran `git rebase --abort`), you may prefer to reset and re-do the merge by hand:

```
$ git reset --hard origin/develop
```

(I tend to avoid HEAD~ with merge commits since I can never remember which parent is which).

Answer (score 1):

You've got two general choices.

The first, and one I normally adopt, is to rebase your version of the `develop` on top of the remote version of `develop`. If there are merge conflicts, you can resolve them as you go (i.e. `rebase --continue` when done).

```
# On local `develop`
git rebase origin/develop
```

If you find there's too many incremental merge conflicts as you go, use the `--interactive` option with rebase and pre-squash all your commits on `develop` from the point which the history of `develop` diverges.

The other option would be to merge the remote version of `develop` into your version. This will inevitably create a merge commit, which may be unsightly if you like keeping Git history as linear as possible.

```
# On local `develop`
git merge origin/develop
```